# Self-serve ad system like Reddit's for Wordpress?

Tags: plugins, php, ads

I'm currently building a Wordpress site and I want to implement a sort of "self-serve" ad system into my site similar to the system Reddit is using.

Is there any sort of "self-serve" ad system or plugin for Wordpress? If not, would it be possible to build something like this for Wordpress?

Comment: You'll have to make your stats available for public. And allow users to target certain areas of sites, eg categories, tags, homepage or single post. I think its possible but requires extensive work. Furthermore you'll need to provide them real time performance stats. Simply you need a team of developers to build such a thing. And I think there is no plugin for this so far.

Comment: Yes it is possible to build such a thing, no, based on the fact you even ask such a question, you don't have the knowledge to build it. Use google's DFP, it is free for small and medium sites.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple plugins to manage and serve ads on your WordPress website. I don’t know the Reddit system, but here are three solutions I have seen used by clients who let advertisers purchase ad space directly.

- Simple Ads Manager – like it, but not always trustworthy in the latest updates
- AdRotate - ok for most self-serving setups
- OIO Publisher – unnecessarily complicated

I ended up developing my own "Advanced Ads" plugin, but it does not yet have an interface where advertisers can purchase ad space directly.

DFP is a full-fledged ad server solution. Most of my clients struggle with it, because the learning curve is high and it very complicated too. There are very few cases in which I would recommend it. Even if you use it, it often makes sense to manage their ad tags through an ad management plugin in WordPress too.

Comment: DFP harder to understand then adrotate? I beg to differ. For sure it is not simpler and if you want only basic stuff then the added complexity is pointless, but ad serving like traffic stats and mailing lists are things that do not belong to content management and are actually a problem that is already solved by several 3rd party tools that are either open sourced or have a nice free tier. Why would anyone want to reinvent the wheel and develope it without the man power and experience the 3rd party tools have? (AFAIK adrotate can't actually rotate ads if you use page caching)